# Why am I receiving KeyError: 'django' when running python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I get an error when I try to start my server.  I'm using Django in a virtual environment.  I've spent hours searching for this & can't find an answer

Here is the error that I received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jaiso\.virtualenvs\storefront2-4TwSyq5h\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 69, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'
```

Here are my installed packages:

> Package               Version
> --------------------- -------
> asgiref               3.5.2
> Django                4.1.2
> django-debug-toolbar  3.7.0
> django-rest-framework 0.1.0
> djangorestframework   3.14.0
> drf-nested-routers    0.93.4
> mysqlclient           2.1.1
> pip                   22.2.2
> Python-Rest-Framework 0.3.14
> pytz                  2022.4
> setuptools            65.3.0 
> six                   1.16.0
> sqlparse              0.4.3 
> tzdata                2022.4
> wheel                 0.37.1

Comment: It's most likely coming from the `TEMPLATES` in the settings. #1 make sure it's there and #2 if you've recently upgrade/have an old settings try and grab a newer version.

Comment: Thanks Nealium but I haven't modified my Templates setting since beginning my project & it was working a couple of days ago.  I uninstalled & reinstalled Django as well as Django Rest Framework.  I even used old version of both to see if it was caused by a new version.  That didn't work either

Comment: Are you sure that your Virtualenv is activated? And your packages are installed inside?

Comment: @claudius Yes, the installed packages list is what's installed in the virtual environment.  When I check the PIP version, its showing the path to the virtual env.        `PS G:\My Folder\Projects\Python Stuff\djangoProject\storefront2> pip -V
pip 22.2.2 from C:\Users\jaiso\.virtualenvs\storefront2-4TwSyq5h\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)`

Answer (score 1):

So I assume you aren't doing custom template stuff, so here's most likely the fix.

Go into your settings.py and make sure your TEMPLATES look like this:

- Take specific Note on the **BACKEND** value

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

---

I changed the **BACKEND** Value to: `template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates` and I got the same error (removed the first `django.`)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\{me}\Envs\tmpdjango\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 71, in __getitem__
    self.run(**options)
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'
```

and it's due to:

```py
# django.templates.util. ~26
def templates(self):
    if self._templates is None:
        self._templates = settings.TEMPLATES

    # stuff chopped out


    for tpl in self._templates:
        try:
            # ********** This Line \/ *******************
            default_name = tpl["BACKEND"].rsplit(".", 2)[-2]

            # 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates'.rsplit(".", 2)[-2]
            # out: 'django'

        except Exception:
            pass # (actually an error here)

    ## futher down
    tpl = {
        "NAME": default_name,
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": False,
        "OPTIONS": {},
        **tpl,
    }

    templates[tpl["NAME"]] = tpl

    # more Stuff
```

and where the error is happening: `alias` seems to always be `django` (not sure why)

```py
# django.templates.util. ~69
def __getitem__(self, alias):

    print('alias',alias)
    # alias == 'django'

    try:
        return self._engines[alias]
    except KeyError:
        try:
            params = self.templates[alias]
            # print(self.templates)
        except KeyError:
            raise InvalidTemplateEngineError(
                "Could not find config for '{}' "
                "in settings.TEMPLATES".format(alias)
            )
```

Comment: Here are my settings for Templates: 

`TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]`

Comment: When I remove "django" @ the beginning of my Backend setting, I get the error 

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'template'`

Comment: @jwill Yeah I also got that 'No module' error, but the other error is further up. Mmmmmm.. I can't recreate it otherwise.. Can you go to: `C:\Users\jaiso\.virtualenvs\storefront2-4TwSyq5h\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py` and place `print(self.templates)` right above `params = self.templates[alias]` (line 69) and give me the output?

Comment: `{'django': {'NAME': 'django', 'DIRS': [], 'APP_DIRS': True, 'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug', 'django.template.context_processors.request', 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}, 'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates'}}`

I got two identical dictionary objects.  I could only paste one of them because of character constraints in these comments

Comment: Wait. I'm an idiot. I went to line # and did see it's `self.engines` that causing a crash. while you have that file open, is line 69 not wrapped in a try+except????- if you look at my edit + the `__getitem__`  there's a try wrapped around that `return self._engines[alias]` line

Comment: Yes, there's a try except wrapped around `return self._engines[alias]`.  When I try to print self._engines, I get 2 empty dictionaries. I guess that's why its not finding the alias (django).  I don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: It looks like this may be a cause as well.  

`File "C:\Users\*\django\template\backends\django.py", line 130, in get_package_libraries    
  File "C:\Users\*\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in run
    raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name 'SkipError' from 'rest_framework.exceptions' (C:\Users\jaiso\.virtualenvs\storefront2-4TwSyq5h\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\exceptions.py)`

Comment: Oh yeah, that's some direction! Googling that says to do `pip install djangorestframework` .. but also try removing `rest_framework` from your installed apps and see if it goes away (just do double check that **that** is the problem)

Comment: I reinstalled djangorestframework.  Same error, I guess I'll have to try something else.  Thanks